# Can Android's CameraX/Camera2 handle at the same time 2 Previews or/and 2 Recordings?

Tags: android, androidx, android-camera2, android-camerax

Is it possible using Android's [CameraX/Camera2](https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/capture-sessions-requests) to preview at the same time on the phone, the image coming from two cameras (e.g. the front and back camera)? The same question holds with recording. Finally, could it even handle all 4 at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Most devices do not support using multiple cameras at the same time; the hardware processing pipeline (the image signal processor, ISP) is often shared between the cameras, and doesn't have enough resources to run both at once.

However, some devices can support at least minimal concurrent camera use, and list support for [FEATURE_CAMERA_CONCURRENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/pm/PackageManager#feature_camera_concurrent).  If so, they'll return a set of camera IDs from [getConcurrentCameraIDs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager#getConcurrentCameraIds()); there's a detailed description at that link on how to set up multiple cameras at once in the correct fashion.

The supported output combinations are listed in one of the tables at [createCaptureSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(android.hardware.camera2.params.SessionConfiguration)); they include:

```
YUV / PRIV <= s720p,    YUV / PRIV <= s1440p,   In-app video / processing with preview.
```

So on such devices, you can indeed run preview at 720p and record video at less than 1440p, from both cameras at the same time.